# React JS: render child according to received state

Tags: reactjs, components

I have one page divided into two parts: left side is dynamic, right side is a slider/carousel. So my components are: MainProfile which is the container, Profile and Credit which have to be displayed in the left side (or one or the other) and MyInfo in the right side. Now, I have to render Profile/Credit according to the state passed in myinfo (when the slider is 1, I need to have Profile in the left side, when the slider is 2, I need to have Credit in the left side). I've tried with this code but console.log always print 'profile' and 'credit'. Where do I am wrong?

MainProfile.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import './MainProfile.css';
import MyInfo from "./my-info/MyInfo";
import Profile from "./profile/Profile"
import Credit from "./profile/Credit"

class MainProfile extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.setContent = this.setContent.bind(this);
    }

    setContent(value){
        if(value===0){          
            console.log('profile')
            return <Profile></Profile>
        }
        else {
            console.log('credit')
            return <Credit></Credit>
        }
    }

    render() {  
        const Aux = props => props.children;
        return(
            <Aux>
                <Col md={7} className={"col-main-profile"}>
                    {this.setContent()||<Profile></Profile>}
                </Col>
                <Col md={4} className={"col-myinfo-main-profile"}>
                    <MyInfo setContent={this.setContent} ></MyInfo>
                </Col>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default MainProfile
```

MyInfo.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import './MyInfo.css';
import { Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import profile from '../../../../assets/Asset 2Profile.png';
import piggie from '../../../../assets/Asset 16pork1 Copy.png';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

class MyInfo extends Component {

    render() {
        var settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        interval: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    this.props.setContent(0)
    return (
        <Col className="comumn-my-info">    
            <Slider {...settings}>
                <CarouselOne></CarouselOne>
                <CarouselTwo></CarouselTwo>
            </Slider>
        </Col>
    );
  }
}
export default MyInfo;

function CarouselOne(props){

    const Aux = props => props.children;
    return(
        <Aux>
            <Row>
                <Col className={"title-my-info"}>
                    Name
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <img
                    className="image-my-info"
                    src={profile}
                    alt="Profile"
                    />
                    <Row style={{height: "20em"}}>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Aux>
    )
}

function CarouselTwo(props){
    const Aux = props => props.children;
    return(
        <Aux>
            <Row>
                <Col className={"title-app"} style={{left: "1.5em"}}>
                    Piggie Bank
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <img
                    className="image-my-info"
                    src={piggie}
                    alt="Piggie Bank"
                    />
                    <Row style={{height: "20em"}}>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Aux>
    )
}
```

Profile and Credit are just jsx code. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to conditionally show or hide a component based on a state value.

You could create a state variable, e.g. `showProfile`

`setState({showProfile:false})`

and then you can use that state variable to conditionally show, e.g.

then further down you can do

```
{this.state.showProfile?(<Profile></Profile>): (<MyInfo setContent={this.setContent} ></MyInfo>)
```

Your `this.props.setContent(0)` callback needs to be called when your carousel changes  slide right? I can't see how that's achieved with your current implementation

Comment: That's a good advice and you're right, I'm not implenting the change of the state. I've tried with calling this.props.setContent() inside the two functions but they are always called and not just when changing slide. This is my main problem.

Comment: do you need additional help?